# Share links for deleted articles 404 instead of redirecting to the deleted post

Tags: bug, articles, sharing, deleted-articles

Share links for articles (those of the form `https://stackoverflow.com/at/{PostId}/{UserId}`) which are generated by the [Share article button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejaJs.png) and the [share link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQuCb.png) work fine for articles that are not deleted.

See, for example, this link https://stackoverflow.com/at/71270196/15497888 successfully redirects to the article [How to use pre-commit to automatically correct commits and merge requests with GitLab CI](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/articles/71270196/how-to-use-pre-commit-to-automatically-correct-commits-and-merge-requests-with-g).

However, when the article is deleted, users who try to use the share link are directed to a 404 page instead of the actual article.

For example, this share link https://stackoverflow.com/at/75025673/15497888 should redirect to https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/azure/articles/75025673/self-help-document-to-handling-errors-due-to-deprecation-of-legacy-tls-protocols (for users with the ability to see these articles) but it does not.

It may be worth noting that other variants of share links do direct successfully to the deleted article.

Here's a summary of some various links and whether or not they work to get to the deleted article:

| Article Id | Link | Link Type | Succeeds |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 75025673 | https://stackoverflow.com/at/75025673/15497888 | Share | [No](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4I3K.png) |
| 75025673 | https://stackoverflow.com/q/75025673/15497888 | Share | [Yes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGXxP.png) |
| 75025673 | https://stackoverflow.com/a/75025673/15497888 | Share | [Yes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGXxP.png) |
| 75025673 | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75025673 | Partial | [Yes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGXxP.png) |
| 75025673 | https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/azure/articles/75025673/self-help-document-to-handling-errors-due-to-deprecation-of-legacy-tls-protocols | Full | [Yes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGXxP.png) |